# asp.net mvc4: adding dynamically parameters on bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, skin, bundles

I would like to do the add skin support for an mvc application, allowing to add multiple skins and let the user select the prefered one.

the skin directory will be received in cookie from the database

In order to make this happen i would like to create a parametrized bundle that takes as input the directory specified for the skin and dynamically creates the bundle for the specified path

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include(
            "~/Content/{skinDirectory}/reset.css",
            "~/Content/{skinDirectory}/site.css",
            "~/Content/{skinDirectory}/grids.css")
            );
```

where {0} is the directory name that i send from the bundle, and i call it in my _Layout page like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css", skinDirectory)
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit late but could probably help someone else. Yes, this is possible.

```
public static class DynamicBundles
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderSkin(string skinDirectory)
    {            
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/" + skinDirectory).Include(
            "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/reset.css", 
            "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/site.css", 
            "~/Content/" + skinDirectory + "/grids.css"));

        return Styles.Render("~/Content/css/" + skinDirectory);
    }
}
```

and then in your _Layout page use

```
@DynamicBundles.RenderSkin(skinDirectory)
```